# Entity Framework Importing Stored Procedure and update its tables

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, crud, objectcontext

I'm working on a project that works with datasets, but now will be with Entity Framework(any version).

My idea is to do the following

- Reuse stored procedures (only selects with parameters - one or more tables)
- To insert, delete and update will use Entity Framework

What is the best way (fast, not complex) to create `INSERT UPDATE DELETE` for those stored procedures?

I tried with `context.SaveChanges` but apparently does not work with imported SQL Server stored procedures. Any ideas for this project?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? And which approach (database-first, model-first, code-first)?

Comment: Sorry, im new on EntityFramework.. the version is 5.0 (but could be any), and i think it's database first (upgrading a system with datasets)